# What is the probability that the given sequence of results is generated by a process?

Tags: probability

Suppose there are coins A and B such that  (=)=0.7  and  (=)=0.5 . At each step you pick one of the coins and record the result of tossing it. If the probability of picking the coin A is 0.4 and coin B is picked otherwise, what is the probability that the following sequence of results is generated by this process?

,,,,

Is it a Bayes' Theorum problem, because the way I am approaching, the probability turns out to be close to 1?

Comment: I would start by first considering the probability of Tails (only the first flip). This can be then expanded upon because the throws are independent. What is the expression that you used to calculate the probability? Please elaborate.

Comment: I actually don't think that you need Bayes for this. Because Bayes would treat a question like: "What is the probability that coin A was chosen, given that the result was Heads?"

Comment: The expression I used was,
P(T) + P(T) + P(T) + P(H) + P(T)
= 3*(0.4*0.3+ 0.6*0.5) + 0.4*0.7 + 0.6*0.5

Comment: Okay, I immediately see where you went wrong. You cannot just add the probabilities like that. Otherwise, at some point you would have a probability larger than 1 !

Comment: So should the probabilities be multiplied instead of added?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by "hiding" the fact that we are choosing between two coins. So let's calculate the probability of Heads by the law of Total Probability:
$$
\begin{split}
P(\text{Heads}) &= P(\text{Heads}|\text{Coin A})P(\text{Coin A is selected})+P(\text{Heads}|\text{Coin B})P(\text{Coin B is selected})\\
&= 0.7 \cdot 0.4 + 0.5 \cdot 0.6\\
&= 0.58
\end{split}
$$
Now we can think that we have only one coin with bias of $0.58$. Now, the probability of the sequence TTTHT can be calculated. Because the throws are independent, we can use the rule
$$
X~\text{ and }~Y~\text{ independent} \Rightarrow P(X~\text{and}~Y) = P(X)P(Y) 
$$
where $X$ and $Y$ are any events. Now
$$
\begin{split}
P(TTTTHT) &= P(T)P(T)P(T)P(H)P(T) \\ &= (1-0.58)^{3} \times (0.58) \times (1-0.58)\\ &\approx 0.0180 
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Did this solution help you? Did you solve the problem?